# Recursively defined nested types (in terms of incomplete types)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, crtp, incomplete-type

Where does the recursion in the definition of `cycle` break ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Recursive
{
    using cycle = struct X : Recursive<X> {}; // would work for Recursive<T> as well
};

int main() 
{
    Recursive<int> x;
    return 0;
}
```

To my surprise the above code [**compiles**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9748d1f7d456b126) - Is it a valid piece of code and if yes what's the meaning (a brief description) of the type `cycle` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `struct X : Recursive<X>` is an example of the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern, but there is **no infinite recursion** taking place unless you access the nested `cycle` type. E.g. `decltype(x)::cycle` is of a different type than `decltype(x)::cycle::cycle`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Recursive
{
    using cycle = struct X : Recursive<X> {};
};


int main() 
{
    int status;
    Recursive<int> x;
    std::cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(x).name(), 0, 0, &status) << '\n';
    std::cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(decltype(x)::cycle).name(), 0, 0, &status) << '\n';
    std::cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(decltype(x)::cycle::cycle).name(), 0, 0, &status) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

This prints

> `Recursive<int>`
>
> `Recursive<int>::X`
>
> `Recursive<Recursive<int>::X>::X`

So the recusion will go on forever, but only if you explicitly access a further nested `cycle` type.

Comment: My question was not on the CRTP but rather on how nested types depending (in a cyclic fashion) on the enclosing class are allowed. It's something common to see eg in linked lists for the node type (pointer though) but the use in the post was new to me. Are we talking about incomplete types and deriving from incomplete types (for sure `Recursive` is yet to be defined when derived from to define `X` and then `cycle`) or do other rules apply when we're talking about derivation?

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou updated: `X : Recursive<X>` is the CRTP. There is neither infinite recursion or any other error there. You can access `cycle` recursively in calling code, and get a new type for every level.