# What is an example practical use of 'recursively nested template'?

Tags: c++, recursion, template-meta-programming

I have found this peculiar pattern mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009560/recursively-defined-nested-types-in-terms-of-incomplete-types).

What is a practical use of such template?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Recursive
{
    using cycle = struct X : Recursive<X> { int a; };
    cycle c;
};

int main() 
{
    Recursive<int> x;
    // cout<< x.c.a; // this gives infinite recursion error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that for things that you do in unity like transform.transform.transform... and you can keep going forever, but other than increasing the verbosity i see no use

Comment: Just because something is possible, doesn't mean that it has a practical use. Disallowing *specifically this construction only* would be hard. Disallowing *this construction and unspecified other things* likely prohibits useful things

Comment: It's an error, there is no use.

Comment: I suspect they have introduced this as an example of a mistake that is easy to make. The usefulness of recursive templates comes when you change the input template type or value in each recursion and you add a specialisation that breaks out of the recursion (at 0 or 1 for example).

Answer (score 0):

One use of the code you wrote is to know what is the template depth of the compiler, by reading the error message when compiling it :)

With `clang`:

```
<source>:8:11: fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 1024
```

With `gcc`:

```
<source>:7:26: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)

 using cycle = struct X : Recursive<X> { int a; };
```